# Trying to understand Microsoft SQL and Windows Server licensing

Tags: windows, sql, licensing

I'm trying to understand how many licenses I'm supposed to purchase and check if I have the correct amount of purchased licenses.
I have Windows Servers & SQL Servers in virtual environment.

From my understanding:

---

Windows Server only:

Server with Windows Server – the license is 'Per CPU'.

A Server with 1 CPU & 2 Cores total - need 1 windows license.

A Server with 2 CPU & 4 Cores total - need 2 windows license.

A Server with 2 CPU & 8 Cores total  - need 2 windows license.

---

SQL Server:

A server with SQL server – The license is 'Per CORE'.

Also needed Windows Server license, amount depends on the number of CPU.

A Server with 1 CPU & 2 Core total – need 2 SQL licenses.

A Server with 1 CPU & 4 Core total – need 2 SQL licenses.

A Server with 2 CPU & 8 Core total – need 4 SQL licenses.

A Server with 2 CPU & 12 Core total – need 6 SQL licenses.

---

Please let me know if my example is correct, So I can be sure I understand the licensing as needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask your authorized reseller. And buy a family pack of Aspirin before talking to them, you'll need it.

Comment: I actually already sent them an email, It's pretty hard to gain information from them, So I'm trying my luck here :P

Comment: Please read the linked post to understand why we will absolutely not touch this topic.

Comment: And as a little common sense - there is no "windows" and "sql server" license. THey are always for a SPECIFIC version and the way they are calculatedf HAS changed, so without knowing WHAT you install, noone can answer.